# The java backend code to the xml code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a basic android application that has several pages accessible from the home page, anyways I change the layout by doing 
`public void main(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}`
and changing the layout to the main game page. Now I want to add characters to it and so I added 
`protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint green = new Paint();
    green.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Rect theRect = new Rect();
    theRect.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2);
    canvas.drawRect(theRect, green);
}` 
but I only want to call it for the "main" or the scene/layout that the game is played in. It appears to not be called at all and that may be due to the fact that I do not completely understand the relationship between the xml and multiple java files and functions. I'm new to android so this may be a stupid question, I just couldn't find anything with multiple web searches, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your game view into activity class:

Class GameView extends View/SurfaceView
{

```
//-- contains onDraw() method
```

}

To add this game view into your activity, you have to do

1. get reference of layout in whioch you want to add this gameview.

   eg: LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
2. Add GameView into this layout

   eg: layout.addView(new GameView());

For more detail, you can get reference from http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame3.html

Hope this helps you